# Adding MDM server to Microsoft Autopilot is not working

Tags: windows, azure, microsoft, microsoft-intune, mdm

Via Microsoft Intune, I want a device that registers with Autopilot to register to the MDM solution I have written. I enter my own MDM server information from this screen.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmUy4.png)

But after wiping the device, it does not send any message to the MDM server. And the device gets this error (0x80070715)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ab7mt.jpg)

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think autopilot is restricted to Intune only. You need to partner with Microsoft to develop something and get it certified

Comment: Edit should *not* totally change the content of the answer like was done here!